# What is safe/GMP prescribed limit of Sodium Benzoate in nacho dough?

Tags: food-safety

I've been cutting nacho triangles from rolled dough and then after lightly pan-roasting them I store them as ready-to-fry, which works and tastes very good but it devlops mould within a week. So, I purchased powdered Sodium Bemzoate, which should work considering the pH of my dough is slightly acidic, but I can't find reliable information about exact GMP limit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect it will depend a bit on where you live. However the limit in the USA is proscribed at 0.1% for foods, this is likely similar to the limits for most "western" countries.

This information was found by searching the FDA website for `"sodium benzoate"` and is found in statute [here](https://www.accessdata.fda.gov/scripts/cdrh/cfdocs/cfcfr/cfrsearch.cfm?fr=184.1733)

Comment: Did you mean 'proscribed' or 'prescribed'?

Comment: Proscribed : forbidden by law. I should have said "proscribed at levels **above** 0.1%"

Comment: Cheers, it was a bit difficult to be sure because, to me at least, a limit can be prescribed, but it would be the given concentration that is proscribed, and they aren't quite the same things. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Prescribed would be a "must have" level. Governments would not recommend a level of an additive unless it was necessary to be there in all cases. In the case of foods it is not normally necessary to add any preservatives for all situations, so a prescription is not needed.